# Data property not working when I am using AOT in Angular 2

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-aot

My resolver is receiving null data values for **route.data['start'];** and **route.data['end'];** in **prediction-resolver.service.ts** when I am using aot option ([Ahead-Of-Time compilation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)) if I am not using this **aot** option is working

Routing file:

```
 {
                path: 'prediction-field/:field_id',
                component: PredictionFieldComponent,
                resolve: {
                    predictions: PredictionResolver,
                    forecasts: WeatherForecastsResolver
                },
                data: {
                 start: moment().subtract(3, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                 end: moment().add(4,'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
            }
```

Reolver file: prediction-resolver.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { PredictionService } from '../../../services/prediction.service';
import { PredictionEntity } from '../../../entities/prediction.entity';

@Injectable()
export class PredictionResolver implements Resolve<PredictionEntity> {

  constructor(private fs: PredictionService, private router: Router) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<PredictionEntity> {
        let start = route.data['start'];
        let end = route.data['end'];
        let field_id = route.params['field_id'];
        return this.fs.getPrediction(start, end, field_id)
           .then( ( resp ) => {
               return resp.content;
           } )
           .catch( ( error ) => {
               console.log('error');
           });
   }
}
```

Comment: Check the angular version, Similar issue reported https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13249